# Derivative of $ \frac{1}{x}$ geometrically

Tags: calculus, derivatives

## Context:

> [image]
>
> "Essence of calculus" series called "Derivative formulas through geometry"- [3rd episode of chapter 3 , 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ&t=616s)
> :

From [10:08 - 12:35](https://youtu.be/S0_qX4VJhMQ?t=607) he discusses the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ geometrically.  After the discussion of the basic idea, it is given as an exercise to solve. I tried solving it but I always come to conclusion that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{x(x+dx)}$, or$ -\frac{1}{(x^2 +xdx)}$. Is it allowed to neglect "$x  dx$"? Or is there another correct method?

## My try:

$$ \begin{align}A_{(lost)} &= A_{(gained)} \\ A_{(lost)} &= x * -d(\frac{1}{x})  \\ A_{(gained)}&= dx \frac{1}{(x+dx)} \end{align}$$

note:-$d(\frac{1}{x})$ is negative because the change was negative (between $x$ and $x+dx$)

That means that $$x * -d(\frac{1}{x}) = dx  \frac{ 1}{(x+dx)}$$

Isolating the $d(\frac{1}{x})$ yields:

$$d(\frac{1}{x}) = -\frac{dx}{x(x+dx)}$$

Dividing the dx from both sides give you the derivative:
$$\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x(x+dx)} = -\frac{1}{(x^2 + x  dx)}$$

Comment: Awesome question! Welcome to the site.  For the best reception, please present your question mathjax [guide here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164)

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, you just have to take the limit $dx\to0$. In that limit $x\cdot dx\to0$ and $d(1/x)/dx$ tends to the derivative.

Comment: I have edited your question this time, but, please try to post your questions using mathjax from the next time!

Comment: The handwaving argument is that $\lim\limits_{dx \to 0}-\frac{1}{(x^2 + x  dx)} = -\frac{1}{(x^2)}$ and with some more rigourous approach this is indeed correct

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is right and very fine but maybe it would be more clear start with finite quantities indicated by $\Delta$ and finally taking the limit, as follows

$$x \cdot\left( -\Delta\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = \Delta x  \frac{ 1}{(x+\Delta x)} \implies \frac{\Delta(\frac{1}{x})}{\Delta x} = -\frac{1}{(x^2 + x  \Delta x)}$$

and taking the limit $\Delta x \to 0$ we have the wanted

> $$\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{d x} = -\frac{1}{x^2 }$$

Answer (score 0):

For the area of rectangle to remain constant the new area should be zero! that is $d(\frac{1}{x})$.$x +dx.(\frac{1}{x}) =0$

$d(\frac{1}{x}).x =-dx.(\frac{1}{x})$

which gives

$\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$